# Why does GeoNames say there are only 73 parks in Mexico?

Tags: api, geonames

I did this GeoNames query

http://api.geonames.org/search?featureCode=PRK&username=genadinik&country=MX&style=full&maxRows=10

and it says there are only 73 parks in all of Mexico. Am I doing something wrong, or GeoNames mostly covers the United States?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.geonames.org/statistics/mexico.html

Area Features (parks,area, ...)

**Parks 71**

71 L.PRK    park    an area, often of forested land, maintained as a place of beauty, or for recreation

65  L.AREA  area    a tract of land without homogeneous character or boundaries

51  L.LCTY  locality    a minor area or place of unspecified or mixed character and indefinite boundaries

8   L.SALT  salt area   a shallow basin or flat where salt accumulates after periodic inundation

6   L.RGN   region  an area distinguished by one or more observable physical or cultural characteristics

5   L.RES   reserve a tract of public land reserved for future use or restricted as to use

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why all those options bring back such small numbers of results.  I am expecting there to be thousands of diff parks and fields there since it is a large country.

Comment: Geonames is sparse in certain countries - you might be better of using OpenStreetMap (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Mexico) or commercial data vendor (Navteq or TeleAtlas)

Comment: @Mappertz I was playing with the OpenStreetMap link you showed me, but I think I don't understand how I'd get the parks out of it.  Under the park section, there isn't much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Geonames is sparse indeed in certain areas.  For example, it's cities1000.txt file (all cities with a population > 1000 people) doesn't list my current hometown (Hixson, TN).  I know there are more than 1000 people in my city.  ;-)